# Text::Csv module in perl, writing data inside a csv

Tags: perl, csv

In the synopsis of [`Text::CSV`](https://p3rl.org/Text::CSV) there's this example

```
my @rows;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
        or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "test.csv" or die "test.csv: $!";

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
    $row->[2] =~ m/pattern/ or next; # 3rd field should match
    push @rows, $row;
}

$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;

$csv->eol ("\r\n");

open $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "new.csv" or die "new.csv: $!";
$csv->print ($fh, $_) for @rows;
close $fh or die "new.csv: $!";
```

I see that it pushes some rows on the array `@rows`, and then the array gets printed line by line inside the output file.

I need to do a similar thing (like checking for a pattern and then save the row to rewrite it on another file later) but I need just one field from each row, and I need to add new fields to the `$row` that is been pushed. How would I do that?

Comment: The synopsis contains several different use case examples. You should read the rest of the documentation. In order to make your question clearer, please [edit] and add example input and desired output.

Comment: Then, push only the field instead of whole row like `push @rows, $row->[2]` and later on push other new fields too.

Comment: Brilliant, why you don't add this as reply so i can flag green?

Comment: Because I don't find it Brilliant. It is just common sense.

Comment: The main problem is that if you push into the array non row elements how can it possibly know where a row ends, i'm sorry but it doesn't work

Comment: @BlueStarry: You need to give an *example* of your input data and the result you require. Please also show your own code rather than a synopsis from the documentation that you know doesn't do what you need

Comment: Hi Borodin, thanks for your reply, i know you're a perl master :) The main problem is that i don't understand what this piece of code does so i can adapt it to my needs. @rows is the array, i don't know what there's inside, i don't know why they use $row, is that an array reference by the way? Why use it...

Comment: @BlueStarry: Yeah, but my problem is that you've only vaguely described your needs so it's very difficult to help! `@rows` is an array of data records, and each record is a reference to an array of fields. You should get into the habit of using [Data::Dump](https://p3rl.org/Data::Dump) (do make the effort to install it -- it's way better than `Data::Dumper`) and `dd \@rows` so that you can see what you're working with. And yes, `$row` contains a reference to an array holding the fields for one row of the input CSV data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to offer a solution when your requirement is so vague, but the general principle is that, instead of pushing `$row` onto the `@rows` array, you should push a reference to an array containing the data that you want in the output. It's convenient to use an anonymous array for this

Suppose you want the output to be `A`, followed by the third column from the row, followed by `Z`. Then you would change the `while` loop like this

You will have to change the test to make the check that you want

```
while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
    next unless $row->[2] =~ /pattern/;
    push @rows, [ 'A', $rows->[2], 'Z' ];
}
```

Comment: Yea this is exactly what i've been looking for. Thanks